# Javascript includes particular case

Tags: javascript, string, filter, include, indexof

In my case I have to keep only titles (or *strings*) containing "eat" , therefore "eating" is also ok, the problem comes with "cheat" since it contains "eat" but it returns out of context titles usually, and at the same time i should keep also the word "cheat meal".

If was not for the "cheat" word per se, i could go with a **if**: `.includes("eat") || .includes("cheat meal")` and I would be done with it. But unfortunately "cheat" also comes without "meal" afterward so how can I exclude "cheat" or "cheating" as words if used without "meal" for instance in this case?

I could do an ugly if statements chain but I'm pretty sure I'm missing some advanced `includes` js method variants which could solve the problem more elegantly

**EDIT examples**:

"what i eat today"  // ACCEPT

"how i cheated on .."  // EXCLUDE

"what's my eating routine" // ACCEPT

"best cheat meal for your week" // ACCEPT

"best cheat meals of the year" // ACCEPT

**EDIT2 full iteration (with solution)**:

```
     let vid = [], vidEat = [];
     for(let j=0; j < vidData.items.length; j++){
          if (vidData.items[j] != undefined){
            vid.push(vidData.items[j].snippet.resourceId.videoId)

            if (/\beat|\bmeal/i.test(vidData.items[j].snippet.title)){
              vidEat.push(vidData.items[j].snippet.resourceId.videoId)
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: What's the logic behind matching `cheat meal`? The `eat` there is inside a `cheat`, which should be excluded, right?

Comment: It should NOT be exluded because the string also has "meal", but if "cheat" was found alone it should be excluded. I'll edit to add examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match words beginning with `eat` or words beginning with `meal`:

```
const probablyRelatedTitles = titles.filter(
  title => /\beat|\bmeal/i.test(title)
);
```

Comment: nice so i guess it's recommended to use .filter in these cases instead of includes. \b means start with and | is the equivalent of js || . The probablyRelatedTitles returns a boolean?

Comment: It sounded like you have an array of strings as the input, so the `.filter` will produce an array containing only those strings which pass the test. The regex was performed on the *string itself*, which was replacing the `.includes`. If you only have one string to check, you can just do `/\beat|\bmeal/i.test(title)` alone.

Comment: Oh no i'm already iterating through the titles, so I'd just need to check for "eat" and "meal" in the current title like: .items[i].snippet.title . Should I use a .includes with the regex you suggested? does it work in node? cause I had some issues before using regex directly like that in node before

Comment: While you could do something like `/\beat|\bmeal/i.test(.items[i].snippet.title)`, using `.filter` in the first place might be a more semantic approach, depends on the broader context. Yes, regular expressions work in Node

Comment: I dont know why it's also getting me titles with "create" and "reatreat" where both words don't start with "eat" but contain it. i'll edit with the full iteration

Comment: It shouldn't. `/\beat|\bmeal/i.test('foo create bar')` produces `false`

Comment: In fact it doesn't make sense to me, I edited with the full iteration i'm using, looks pretty straightforward to me in regards to the method you suggested

Comment: Are you sure you're checking `vidEat` afterwards, and not just `vid`?

Comment: I have another place in the page where I'm using the iteration and forgot to change with new code there.. it works.